# How to configure an Eclipse Java format that avoids joining Javadoc lines?

Tags: java, eclipse, formatting, format, javadoc

I'm running into a peculiar behavior when formatting Java code using Eclipse (see image, below).  Even though that I have "Never join lines" checked under Comments->General Settings, it seems to want to join lines within a Javadoc comment when they use `{@code}` tags.

I've found [one possibly-related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6181065/bad-line-breaking-in-eclipse-javadoc-comments) on StackOverflow, but it seems to be my problem in reverse.  I only suspect it could be related due to the presence of `{@code}` tags.

Here's the Eclipse Java format setting:
[image: Never join lines checked]

Here's the improperly-formatted Javadoc comment:
[image: Improperly-formatted Javadoc comment]

Any ideas on how to get this to work, such as a magic setting I am overlooking?  To be clear, I am **not** interested in:

1. Disabling formatting on Javadoc blocks.  I want formatting to be applied.
2. Using `@formatter:off` and `@formatter:on` or any other manual/workaround approaches.  There are a ton of instances of this in the code I am trying to format.

Answer (score 1):

How about adding `<br>` between your `{@code}` statements ? This should give you the following result:

```
 * 
 * @return {@code true} - if the override was successfully recorded.<br>
 *         {@code false} - if the override was not successfully recorded.
 *
```